# Transparent border-color not working as expected

Tags: css

For some reason `border-color: transparent;` is not actually transparent if paired with any `background-color`. I made a small demonstration below. You can clearly see the blue background color of `div#two` and its red border in the first snippet even though `div#one` is above it. This is expected as the border and the background of `div#one` are transparent.

However in the second snippet even though the border has not changed at all and only the background of `div#one` has changed its color, you can no longer see the red border! Why is that? Shouldn't the border of `div#two` remain visible as `div#one`'s border is still fully transparent?

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid;
}

#one {
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;

  position: absolute;
}

#two {
  border-color: firebrick;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid;
}

#one {
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: #ccc;       /* <--- changed */

  position: absolute;
}

#two {
  border-color: firebrick;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's all about `background-clip` which default value is `border-box` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) so the background will logically cover the border area.

Change it to something else and you will see the border in the second case.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

#one {
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: #ccc;       /* <--- changed */

  position: absolute;
}

#two {
  border-color: firebrick;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is intended behavior. Background color covers the border of an element as well so you are seeing the background color of the element through the transparent border (border overlays on top of the edges of the background). You can either wrap the element in another element and use the transparent border on the outer element or use margin (but this can get hairy in various situations) - in that case you may want to use something like flexbox.

```html
<div id="one" class="outer"><div class="bg"></div></div>
<div id="two" class="outer"><div class="bg"></div></div>
```

```css
.outer {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

#one > .bg {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#one {
  border-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
}

#two {
  border-color: firebrick;
}

#two > .bg {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jimbo2150/a6wne9jz/1/